# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setProgress'

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox

I use Orfeo ToolBox(OTB) in conjunction with QGIS 3.4.
So. I use the qgis-otb plugin.

I was not a problem when I linked OTB with my company's PC,
but when I tried the same way on my personal laptop, I got the following error.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setProgress'

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ConfigDialog.py", line 86, in apply
    self.config_widget.accept()
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ConfigDialog.py", line 325, in accept
    setting.setValue(str(self.items[setting].text()))
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\ProcessingConfig.py", line 293, in setValue
    self.validator(value)
  File "C:\qgis-plugins\qgis-otb-plugin\otb\OtbAlgorithmProvider.py", line 267, in validateAppFolders
    OtbUtils.executeOtb(commands, feedback=None)
  File "C:\qgis-plugins\qgis-otb-plugin\otb\OtbUtils.py", line 76, in executeOtb
    feedback.setProgress(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setProgress'
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This bug [was fixed last week](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin/issues/25) in the plugin. Update it or redownload the latest version and it should work.